# ubuntu 22.04 xrdp could not start log

Tags: xrdp, ubuntu-22.04

trying to start xrdp with

```
sudo systemctl start xrdp
```

fails with error:

```
could not start log
```

What is missing?

Comment: raspberry pi? Remount your partition as writable.

Comment: I run it on a PC

Comment: please check the port that xrdp is using. the port that xrdp uses may have been occupied by other application

Answer (score 0):

found this and it worked for me

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/80mate-environment
```

Add:

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

before the closing fi